# Uniswap v2 - How to get the amount of a token that a liquidity provider holds in a liquidity pool?

Tags: blockchain, uniswap

I have a collection of wallet addresses and I need to find the amount of a token that each of those addresses hold in some liquidity pools. Lets suppose the liquidity poll is for token A and B. So I need to find the amount of token A that each addresses has in the liquidity pool. How can I get that?

To be clear, I am not talking about the `lp_token`, rather I am talking about one of the tokens that the addresses have staked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The amount of underlying tokens a liquidity provider owns in a Uniswap v2 pool is proportional to the provider's share of the LP tokens.

For example, let's say the pool has 1000 USDC in its reserves, and the `totalSupply` of the LP token is equal to 100. Then someone owning 1 LP token would have the rights to 10.0 USDC in the pool.

Example Python code, for the USDC/WETH pool:

```
from web3 import Web3

web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(PROVIDER_URL))
pair = '0xB4e16d0168e52d35CaCD2c6185b44281Ec28C9Dc'
contract = web3.eth.contract(address=pair, abi=v2_pool_abi)

reserves = contract.functions.getReserves().call()
reserve_usdc = reserves[0]
total_supply = contract.functions.totalSupply().call()

lp_address = '0x76E2E2D4d655b83545D4c50D9521F5bc63bC5329' 
lp_balance = contract.functions.balanceOf(lp_address).call()
lp_usdc = reserve_usdc * lp_balance / total_supply   
usdc_decimals = 6
lp_usdc_adjusted = lp_usdc / 10 ** usdc_decimals
print(f"liquidity provider {lp_address} has {lp_usdc_adjusted} USDC in USDC/WETH pool")
```

Comment: thanks a lot.. a quick followup question, is it the same for other swaps as well (i.e sushi, ape, pancake) etc. if i am not wrong they are just a fork of uni, so it should be the case right?

Comment: yes - uniswap v2 code should work with most of these

Answer (score 1):

```
    const Web3 = require('web3');
    const web3 = new Web3(`https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/${process.env.INFURA}`); // Web3 instance connected to Ethereum mainnet
    const abi = require("/ABI/UNISWAPV2/USDC/WETH-USDC.json")
    function getReserves(factoryAddress) {
    try {
        const factory = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, factoryAddress);
        factory.methods.getReserves().call()
        .then(result => {
                console.log("WETH", result._reserve1/(10**18));
                console.log("USDC",result._reserve0/(10**6));
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error(error);
            });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
    }
getReserves("0xB4e16d0168e52d35CaCD2c6185b44281Ec28C9Dc")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).